# Why isn't my ImageBackground the same inside a TouchableOpacity in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my app, I have a screen that shows three rows that contain some text and a background image.

I used to only put the image, but I want to be able to press on the images to execute an action. This was my code before and it worked properly :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, View } from 'react-native'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import SelectorBox from '../../components/workout/SelectorBox';

const EXERCISE = require('../../assets/workout/exercise.jpg');
const MUSCLES = require('../../assets/workout/muscles.jpg');
const ROUTINE = require('../../assets/workout/routine.jpg');

export default function SelectorScreen() {
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
            <SelectorBox image={MUSCLES} title={t('workout.muscleGroups')} />
            <SelectorBox image={EXERCISE} title={t('workout.exercises')} />
            <SelectorBox image={ROUTINE} title={t('workout.routines')} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

export default function SelectorBox(props) {
    return (
            <ImageBackground source={props.image} style={styles.background}>
                <View style={styles.titleBar}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground> 
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    },
    titleBar : {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width, 
        height: 60, 
        backgroundColor: '#ffb623',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: "900",
        fontSize: 32,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    }

})
```

However, when I change the code, all my SelectorBox disappear...

```
export default function SelectorBox(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.option}>
            <ImageBackground source={props.image} style={styles.background}>
                <View style={styles.titleBar}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground> 
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    option: {
        flex: 1,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        // backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    background: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    },
    titleBar : {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width, 
        height: 60, 
        backgroundColor: '#ffb623',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: "900",
        fontSize: 32,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    }

})
```

I would like to be able to keep it like this screenshot everywhere. Right now, the screen is empty. (blue background, this is what i set it to)

Can you guide me ?
[image]

Comment: Use `TouchableOpacity` instead of `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. `TouchableOpacity` is like a `View` with touch functionality; `TouchableWithoutFeedback` clones each children and does not properly handle flex style.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Hi ! I changed it, but it all stays the same...

Comment: Try to debug the issue by steps. Then now try and and import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of `react-native-gesture-handler`. Does the `backgroundColor: 'red'` color works if uncomment it from the `option` style?

Comment: Which version of `react-native` and `react-native-gesture-handler` are you using? I've had some issues using `react-native-gesture-handler@1.5.0` with `react-native@0.61.x`.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. It seems that the issue was from importing form 'react-native-gesture-handler'. I should have checked the auto-import... I would like to put your answer as validated. Can you answer the question directly so I can do that (if you want of course) ? Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Of course. I've added an answer. Small things like these can cause lots of headaches.

Comment: I just upvoted and set as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug the issue by steps.

Try and and import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of `react-native-gesture-handler`. Does the `backgroundColor: 'red'` color works if uncomment it from the option style?

#### Change this:

```jsx
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

#### to import from RN:

```jsx
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
```

You should consider of using [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) instead of [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback):

> **TouchableWithoutFeedback**
>
> Do not use unless you have a very good
>   reason. All elements that respond to press should have a visual
>   feedback when touched.
>
> TouchableWithoutFeedback supports only one child. If you wish to have
>   several child components, wrap them in a View. Importantly,
>   TouchableWithoutFeedback works by cloning its child and applying
>   responder props to it. It is therefore required that any intermediary
>   components pass through those props to the underlying React Native
>   component.